# Equidistribution modulo 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, diophantine-approximation

We know that the time spent by the sequence $na \mod 1$, $n$ ranging from $1$ up to $x$ and $a$ irrational, at any interval of length $\delta$ is approximately $\delta x$. There are known results when $\delta$ is allowed to decrease with $x$? I need equidistribution when $\delta= 1/ \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: look up "discrepancy"

Comment: My prelimary search on the mentioned keyword does not allow that length of the intetval decreases

Comment: Start with Hermann Weyl(?).

Comment: I think if you want equidistribution over shrinking intervals, you need to restrict $a$ to be far from rationals. For example, if $a=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2^{-j!}$, then you get equidistribution at scale $\delta=2^{-n!}$ at time roughly $x=2^{n!}$. But if you want equidistribution at scale $\delta=2^{-2n!}$, you get this at time roughly $x=2^{(n+1)!}.

Answer (score 9):

This response is to make Anthony Quas's comment more precise. Assume that the inequality
$$\|q a\|\leq\frac{1}{8q^2}\tag{$\ast$}$$
holds for some positive integer $q$. Then the numbers $na\bmod 1$ for $n\in\{q,2q,3q,\dots,4q^2\}$ all lie in an interval $I$ of length $1/(2q)$. Writing $x=4q^2$, we see that $I$ has length $1/\sqrt{x}$, and it contains at least $2\sqrt{x}$ numbers $na\bmod 1$ with $n\in\{1,2,3,\dots,x\}$. That is, if ($\ast$) has infinitely many solutions, then the sought equidistribution fails.

Comment: The set of $\alpha$ for which $(*)$ has infinitely many solutions has measure zero, I think.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sure, this follows from the Borel-Cantelli lemma. See also Khintchine's theorem in diophantine approximation.

Comment: This is very helpful. Is the converse of what you are saying also true: if $\liminf q^2\|qa\|=\infty$, then one obtains equidistribution at the scale $1/\sqrt x$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I don't think so. In the other direction, the natural thing to do is to bound the discrepancy with the Erdős-Turán inequality. Based on this, $\liminf q\|qa\|>0$ yields equidistribution at scale $f(x)/\sqrt{x}$ for any $f(x)$ tending to infinity. Of course $\liminf q\|qa\|>0$ is a much stronger assumption than $\liminf q^2\|qa\|=\infty$, and $f(x)/\sqrt{x}$ is much bigger than $1/\sqrt{x}$, so I don't know.